# Removing text from an undeclared div via CSS

Tags: css, html, text, joomla

Subj. I've got a module for Joomla (don't blame me for using joomla, it's not me, i'm just helping my friend) with advertisment. The problem is that i can't get source codes for any modules, so I have to fix most of the problems via CSS (display:none method mostly).

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
        <a style="text-decoration:none; color: #c0c0c0; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 5pt; " target="_blank" href="http://joomline.ru/">ADVERTISMENT HERE</a>
</div>
```

If only div was declared, I would simply make it invisible using the display:none method...

Looking forward to help !

EDIT:

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="jlvkgroup41016340" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; height: 301px; width: 270px;">
         ...
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> ... </script>
    <div style="text-align: right;">
        <a style="text-decoration:none; color: #c0c0c0; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 5pt; " target="_blank" href="ADVERT LINK">TEXT ADVERT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there any parent elements which could be referenced in the selector?

Comment: And what are you actually trying to do? Hide the advertisement text?

Comment: Curt, there are other elements which are used in order to make the module work (it's actually a social network widget).

Comment: David, yes, i need to get rid of the advertisement.

Comment: can you not simply add a class or id to the div tag and then use display:none; in the css?

Comment: i would if i could :) i have no access to source code

Comment: can you not get your friend to add it in then? Would probably make life a lot more simple ;)

Comment: Why wouldn't you have access to the source code in a GPL application?
In the meantime you might want to look at rereplacerhttp://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/rereplacer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to hide the link (with that *specific* `href`):

```
a[href^="http://joomline.ru"] {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DynAX/).

Based on the newly-added HTML, you can target the specific `a` element using sibling-combinators:

```
#jlvkgroup41016340 + script + div a {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DynAX/4/).

This targets the `a` elements that are a descendant of a `div` element that's the immediately-adjacent sibling of a `script` element that is itself the adjacent sibling of the element with the `id` of `jlvkgroup41016340`.

Or:

```
#jlvkgroup41016340 ~ div a {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DynAX/3/).

This targets the `a` descendants of a `div` which is the later-sibling of the element of `id="jlvkgroup41016340"`.
References:

- [General-sibling (`~`) combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).
- [Adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).

Comment: ^ This method, unfortunately, didn't work for me, no idea why.

Comment: Maybe `display: none !important` (I know !important is horrible but it may be necessary here)

Comment: It depends on browser-implementation, unfortunately. But, again unfortunately, without specific targeting (with `id`, `class` or inheritance) this is the *best* I can think of to suggest.

Comment: This class has this DIV + 1 declared DIV and a script. Maybe it is possible to make undeclared div invisible by making the whole class invisible and exclude other elements somehow?

Comment: Without your code (and, please, [add it to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13534270/edit) not to the comments) I'm unable to make a suggestion. If the `div` you can target (by `id` or `class`) *precedes* this one then yes, that can work (depending on your code, of course); otherwise you may have to use JavaScript.